# Error in pivot_table : Dropna=False : array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, pivot-table

Iam trying to run the following statement of pivot_table function of pandas. However, I want to retain NaN values for which I include "dropna=False" but the following error occurs :

Statement :
`df=pd.pivot_table(data=df_a,index=['ID','Year','Team','Name','Sex','Age','Height','Weight','NOC','Games','Season','City','Sport','Event'],columns='Medal',aggfunc=len,dropna=False)`

Error :
`` array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size. ``

This works fine if I don't include dropna functionality. But I want to retain null values. Please help me to fix this issue :)

Comment: you need to use 64bit python not 32bit

Comment: Did you try to fill NAN with zero and do it? df = df.fillna(0) and do pivot without dropna option.

Comment: Also, you can try with fewer indexes and see what happens? If the error doesn't appear with less index, it might be a memory problem?